# In Twilio How Do I GATHER while on an active call?

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml

We are building a custom phone system (PBX) on twilio.

When a caller calls in, a few recordings are played and then we have a dial verb. Within the dial verb can be one or more `<number>` nouns, which allow us to create 1 or more calls depending on the need (ring group).

When one of the numbers answers, and is connected I need to be able to put in a GATHER verb so that the person answering the phone, can easily transfer the caller to another predetermined extension. Ideally, they would just be able to tap in 100# and the caller would be disconnected and the transferred to extension 100.

How do I accomplish this?

I have the following so far, but it seems I cannot nest Gather inside of anything else, so I am at a loss as to how to accomplish what I need.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Play>http://example.com/thankyouforcalling.mp3</Play>
    <Play>http://example.com/anothermessage.mp3</Play>
    <Play>http://example.com/connecttosales.mp3</Play>
    <Dial action="inboundcomplete" record="true" timeout="90">
       <Number>555-555-1211</Number>
       <Number>555-555-1210</Number>
    </Dial>
</Response>
```

Any help on this would be great!

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The best thing to do here is actually dial your callers into a conference. You can then use the `hangUpOnStar` attribute of the [`<Dial>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial) verb to allow a user to drop out of the call and make changes to it with a [`<Gather>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/gather) verb in another bit of TwiML.

This can be quite a confusing process, but we have two blog posts on the matter depending on your preference of language. Either check out this post on [warm phone call transfers with Python, Flask and Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2015/09/warm-phone-call-transfers-with-python-flask-and-twilio-voice.html) or this post on [how to warm transfer a call with Java and Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2015/08/how-to-warm-transfer-a-call-with-java-and-twilio-voice.html).

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: So. I figured out the conference thing yesterday, and ahve it half way working. My issue has changed a little:

so the caller is in a conference, using the api I can initiate a single call to another number, but how do I ring multiple numbers with the api at the same time so I can still have my ring group? This leads me to ask how do I direct the api to only connect the first number to answer to the conference?

Comment: You could still have your ring group, but you'd need to initiate calls to the numbers via the REST API instead of via the `<Dial>` verb. You could then either try a call until it is answered or otherwise then move on to the next, or generate multiple calls and cancel the others once one answers.

Comment: @philnash Why is this the recommended way? This seems like a dirty dirty hack to me...

Comment: @That1Guy It depends on what you are trying to achieve. If you need all people in a conference to be able to control it. If you have an agent with an interface that you are building, then you could build the controls into that interface rather than as part of the call. If you have a more specific question feel free to ask and point me at it.