# Gathering speech during outbound twilio voice call

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-programmable-voice, twilio-node

I am trying to create a voice call from twilio to a number using programmable voice.
I also intend to gather recipient's speech transcribed. However, the documentation contains examples and tutorials only for inbound voice calls.

This is what I have tried-

Initiating voice call:

```
  client.calls
  .create({
    twiml: `<Response><Gather input="speech" action="https://ngrok-url-for-my-local-server/voice" method="POST" speechTimeout="5"><Say>Hey there, How are you?</Say><Pause length="4" /></Gather></Response>`,
    to: toPhoneNumber,
    from: myPhoneNumber,
  })
  .then((call) => {
    console.log(call.sid)
    console.log(call)
  })
  .catch((e) => {
    console.log(e)
  })
```

Code in handler for gathering speech-

```
const VoiceResponse = twiml.VoiceResponse

const res = new VoiceResponse()
res.gather()
console.log(res.toString())
```

However I am not getting anything useful in the console.
Can anybody point me to a useful tutorial or example or tell me what I should do ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to first make the call and then modify the call to gather.

When you make the call using the new VoiceResponse() call you will be returned a  SID for the call. Next, use that SID to modify a call that is in progress by redirecting to the Twiml to gather the digits.

You will have three legs:

1. Make the outbound call (you provided this code in your questions).
2. [Modify the active outbound call](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/tutorials/how-to-modify-calls-in-progress) by using the call's SID to redirect to a Gather twiml.
3. After the gather has finished tell the call what do to using the action parameter of the gather. Here is an [example](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/gather#).

If you are trying to go for a conference bridge type feature where you press * to move into an admin type menu, you will need a more complex solution involving a [conference call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35758804/in-twilio-how-do-i-gather-while-on-an-active-call).

Comment: Hey jassent, I am making the call with `client.calls.create` (refer to question), do I need to give any twilm there? And where should I provide with the webhook url where I will update the code with gather twiml ?

Comment: Your twiml is on the right track. You need the "action" to process the digits. Refer to the [Gather node.js example](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/gather). In the example, you will need to write the method/controller for "process_gather.php". So after the twiml gathers the digits it will call the process_gather.php where you will then handle the digits. process_gather.php can then [update the call in progress](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/call-resource?code-sample=code-update-a-call-in-progress-with-twiml&code-language=Node.js&code-sdk-version=3.x) using the Twilio REST Api.